# is it possible to launch shell commands through a webpage? what language should I use?

Tags: shell

I want to make a simple GUI for my server with options like: sudo shutdown -h now.

I have doubts cause while thinking about this, I realized that apache runs as user www, which is quite limited. So html page served via apache will have limited access... is this so?

If yes, how do applications like webmin work?

Thanks.

Comment: All security issues and precautions with this aside: doing a `shutdown -h` is not to wise is it? Unless you have physical access to the machine you will never be able to access it again.

Comment: nope, I can wake it up easily by using wol (wake on lAN) which surprisingly also works from the internet... so wol on steroids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put up a simple web page with for example Python or Ruby using a `system` call to run such commands, but **only for static, prepared commands which you have tested manually and exhaustively** and **only if you have good security in place already** to avoid DOS attacks and vandalism. These points are extremely important because you *really* don't want anyone else to have your machine at their disposal. You can easily set up `sudo` to allow static commands from `wwwrun` with `sudo visudo`.

Even so, it's <strike>probably</strike> a *lot* safer to use secure protocols actually designed for secure remote work, such as **`ssh`** (together with `ssh-copy-id` for convenience and security).

Comment: ... and only if the webserver user (e.g. wwwrun) is in `/etc/sudoers` or has the required permissions otherwise.